Best practice for storing user uploaded files: Laravel 8
Using Laravel 8. Users can upload files and they get saved into myApp/storage/app/documents/{user_uuid}/{filename}. I want the already uploaded files to be embedded into a profile page shown to the logged in users.
What would be the best practice path to store the files in and show them to logged in users? storage/app/public?

No, there is no security concern if you want to store the file in storage/app/public/ location.But for that you need to create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public by running the command php artisan storage:link so that these files can be accessible.

It's unclear if you're asking for best practice, asking if files in storage/app/public/ are public or asking for help to make storage/app/documents work. You can easily test the second question yourself: what happens if you request the URL and you are not logged in?

The best practice is to store them in the storage folder with using a spatie/medialibrary package
store them with a uuid and create different collection according to your needs, then make a public route to return that file or either start downloading that file with that uuid as a parameter
